# Upload Failed You are required to sign in to upload your changes to this location

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-foundation

I have oppened a word document from sharepoint and edited it
When i clicked on SAVE i got this message on ribbon in the header of the document

```
 Upload Failed You are required to sign in to upload your changes to this locatio
```

This occured after 15 minutes from when i oppened the document. and nothing happen when i click on "Sign in" button on the bar. 
Is there any whay to handle this, maybe make the session longer

[image]

Comment: Did you ever resolve this problem? I have the same issue.